# Google Drive files.list giving 404 on any sub root folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I am little confused with Drive files.list function (v2/v3). For testing it I used google UI that they provide on the [reference site](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list). For google drive ID if I  enter my root drive ID, it returns list of the files. If I enter any subfolder under root and use that as driveID I get 404 not found. I've searched Internet and based on that it should return list of files from that subfolder. I am missing something it appears, some help would be appreciated.

Comment: welcome to stack please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your solution.  without seeing your code its hard to help you.

Comment: Hello, there is no code, it's GUI API tested that google provides.

Comment: Well if theres no code then its not programming related you might have better luck on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is code related. So it appears https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list this is the answer on my question. Files.list works only with root drive ID. Guess it's by design.

Comment: Can you please share the **Request Parameters** used? Doesn't matter if this is a link or a JSON payload.

Comment: Sure:
Corpora: Drive
Driveid: 3434543543rt3443r4343543
includeItemsFromAllDrives: true
supportsAllDrives: true
supportsTeamDrives: true
This only works for root drive, not working for any subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

### You have misunderstood the driveId parameter use Children: list (API V2) instead

The parameter **driveId** stands for `ID of the shared drive to search.` Which means only Shared Drive Id not a folder ID.

As a workaround I'd use the [Children: list method from V2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/children/list) where you can get a list of the children given a Folder Id (Shared or normal Drive).

By using the mentioned above method you'll get a list of IDs that you can use later in order to treat single files.